# Visual Studio Code coloring of numbers in e.g. c++ files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm doing my first steps with VSCode and wanted to change the colorization of the view sources.
Now I'm looking very long for a possibility, unfortunately, I didn't find a way to change the color of a hex-number including the '0x'.
I changed the color in my global setting.json like that

```
...
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "comments": "#00FF22",
        "numbers": "#FF0000"
}
...
```

but what I got is **0x***0000*, where the 0x is still the normal color and the 0000 is shown in red.

Does anybody have an idea of what I'm doing wrong or what shall I change to get the prefixes '0x' also in the defined color?

Thanx a lot and
all the best
Michael

Comment: Thanx for improving... :) I'm not a native speaker... BR Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hex constant is made from 2 Textmate rules

Add this setting

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      { "scope":"keyword.other.unit.hexadecimal.cpp",
        "settings": {"foreground": "#FF0000"}
      },
      { "scope":"constant.numeric.hexadecimal.cpp",
        "settings": {"foreground": "#FF0000"}
      }
    ]
  }
```

For python use `constant.numeric.hex.python`

Use command `Developer:Inspect Editor Tokens and Scope` to find the Textmate rules to use.

Comment: Thanx a lot... thats what I wanted to see... I'll have a look at the hint with the `Developer:...` BR Michael

Comment: Hi again, is there a possibility to set these values/colors for python as well?

Comment: Thanx..it works propper for the number itself, but the '0x' is still in a different color.
I used **constant.numeric.hex** and **keyword.other.unit** to do it not for one language only, but unfortunately I didn't find the 'scope' for the prefix with python.

Comment: @Michael `storage.type.number.python`

Comment: where do you find all these things... I did many search and tried to find that, but... ok, maybe I started my search with the wrong words... nevertheless, thanx a lot!